# How to add code to set headers to a simple ruby webrick command line?

Tags: ruby, http, http-headers, webrick

When I need a test web server that can serve a few files from some directory, I really like the simplicity of

`ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8888`

then browse to `localhost:8888`.

However, sometimes I'd like to add a tiny little bit to that, for example, set a specific mime type for a specific extension (I can edit `/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httputils.rb`, but I'd rather not mess with system files), or add an `Expires:` header.

It seems like adding a header isn't that complicated, for example, looking at https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/setting-expires-http-response-header.822995/.

However, I have *zero* knowledge about ruby, so I have no clue about how to add that to my command line. I guess it's just "create a file that has a subclass, pull it in, and tell ruby to use the subclass", but well .. that answer is 3 steps beyond me.

So, I'd be grateful for an answer that says "Put `this` into a file, then add `that` to your command line", with copy/pasteable examples of `this` and `that`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Put this into a file *server.rb* for example:

```
require 'webrick'                                                                                                          

class Server < WEBrick::HTTPServer                                                                                         
  def service(req, res)                                                                                                    
    super                                                                                                                  
    one_hour = 60 * 60                                                                                                     
    t = Time.now.gmtime + one_hour
    res['Expires'] = t.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
  end                                                                                                                      
end                                                                                                                        

root = File.expand_path('.')                                                                                               
server = Server.new(Port: 8000, DocumentRoot: root)                                                                        

trap('INT') { server.shutdown } # Ctrl-C to stop                                                                                            

server.start
```

Then run this in console:

```
ruby server.rb
```

It will serve files list from current directory.

Comment: I made a little change so the Expires header is in the format that's expected by the client in case someone else comes here later to copy-paste. But indeed, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!